# Check if items, from an array, exists in a page. If so, alert it. If not, refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

So, I had this userscript that would look for a string inside a page. If it doesn't find it, it refreshes the page 4 seconds later:

```
var item = 'apple';
if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf(item) > -1){
    setTimeout(function() {
        alert(item + " was found");
    }, 150);
}else{
    setTimeout(function()
               {
        location.reload(true);
    }, 4000);
}
```

This code is working perfectly. But then, I wanted to search for more than 1 item, with an array:

```
var item = [
    'apple',
    'peach'
];
for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++){
    if(document.body.innerHTML.toString().indexOf(item[i]) > -1){
        player.play();
        setTimeout(function() {
            var curitem = item[i];
            alert(item[i] + " was found");
        }, 200);
    }
}
//else{
//    setTimeout(function()
//               {
//        location.reload(true);
//    }, 4000);
//}
```

But I am stuck, I don't know:

1. How to alert the item of the array that was found? The way it is right now, it alerts 'undefined was found'.
   This means that the script is working, it's finding the items in the array. But in the alert shows as 'undefined'.
2. How do I refresh the page if nothing was found?

Comment: move "var curitem = item[i]" above the setTimeout call and use "alert(curitem+" was found");" instead, "i" is out of scope

Comment: @Daniel, [moving the goalposts like that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) is not allowed.  Your new problems are easy, but they are also *new*.  Ask a new question for those ***after*** the *original* question here is resolved -- which it seems the answers below do.

Comment: @BrockAdams I just was able to do that before, and the problems are _new_ with the new solution provided :/ So I didn't know about that, sorry.

Comment: @Daniel, there was only one problem with the new solution, and it was fixed yesterday.  The other things were new features that were neither present in the original, broken, code, nor in the original question.  Your original question is answered.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this.  I prefer regex because it gives greater power and is generally faster than looping, for large numbers of terms.

Code like:

```js
var items = [
    'apple',
    'peach'
];
var itmRegEx = new RegExp (`(${ items.join("|") })`);

var itmMtch  = document.body.innerHTML.match (itmRegEx);
if (itmMtch  &&  itmMtch.length) {
    //player.play();
    //setTimeout (alert, 200, itmMtch[1] + " was found");
    setTimeout (console.log, 200, itmMtch[1] + " was found");
}
else {
    console.log ("Reloading...");
    //setTimeout ( () => {location.reload (true);}, 4000);
}
```

Note:

1. `toString()` is unnecessary.
2. This allows the full power of regex.  For example, expressions like `'apple\\b'` -- which matches "apple", but not "apples".
3. Beware using `innerHTML`.  This will match things like
   `<a href="virusserver.net/badapple">free!</a>`.
   If what you want appears visibly on the page, use `textContent` instead.
4. Note the modern form of `setTimeout()`.
5. `document.body` casts a wide, slow, net.  If you can, target the node(s) you are interested in by class or id.
6. `location.reload` is a special case where the parameterized version of `setTimeout()` will not work.  (It gives "Illegal invocation" error.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated my post with the current problems.

Answer (score 1):

This will find the first occurrence in the array. Div id `content` is used here because the script is part of the body in the example snippet.

```js
var item = [
    'apple',
    'peach'
];

//make sure that items dont contain special regex chars
var itemRe = new RegExp(item.join("|"));
var result = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML.toString().match(itemRe);

if (result) {
  //player.play();
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert(result.toString() + " was found");
  }, 200);
} else {
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload(true);
  }, 4000);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">gfg</div>
```